# how to add values to an array without updating the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two rows (longitude and latitude) in my MySQL table. I want to get the two rows into a 2-dimensional array such that when the values (longitude and latitude) change in the database the values will be added to the array. Not that the values will be updated.

```
 while($mRow = $resultMarker->fetch_assoc()){
      $myArrayForMarkers [] = $mRow['latitude'];
      $myArrayForMarkers [] = $mRow['longitude'];       
  }

  print_r($myArrayForMarkers);
```

The issue I have in the code above is that instead of the new values to be added from the database to the array, the values in the array are being updated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Store the values in `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` instead as it'll always update when you refresh because the code is re-executing.

Comment: Do you want the values to be added to your array when you refresh the whole page or what exactly?

Comment: Can you put how the output should look like? and what will be the input

Comment: Same here, the terminology you use is misleading, and your goal isn't stated clearly. Your question will be closed soon as unclear if you don't correct that.

Comment: Yes I want the values to be added when I refresh the page @xander

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, the wording of your question makes little sens. For example, I don't undurstand what you mean by '*Not that the values will be updated.*' nor how your array being '*updated*' is different to '*the values will be added to the array*'.

Please clarify your question, especially if my answer doesn't solve it so that those who will eventually come here while looking after a solution can understand if your issue is the same than theirs.

I get that you try to craft a 2-dimension array.
The code you provided produces 1-dimension arrays.

If you want to store your datas in a 2-dimension array, I only see two solutions :

Either your main array has two subarrays, each containing one type of data :

```
while ($mRow = $resultMarker->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myArrayForMarkers['latitude'][] = $mRow['latitude'];
    $myArrayForMarkers['longitude'][] = $mRow['longitude'];
}
```

or en
each entry of your array itself contains both information :

```
while ($mRow = $resultMarker->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myArrayForMarkers[] = array('latitude' => $mRow['latitude'], 'longitude' => $mRow['longitude']);
}
```

That's the most I can do right now, since I don't understand the rest of your question.